# Using ANN in time series with limited observations

Tags: time-series, neural-networks

I'm trying to predict weekly market shares over time with a small data set (190 examples and 4 inputs).

My questions are the following:

1. Is there a particular technique for small number of observations? (i.e., I heard that you could train a network with white noise to avoid the cross-validation.)
2. Do I have to filter data when i'm working with time series? (i.e., account for seasonal dummies)

Answer (score 1):

1) You are talking about regularization: there are many ways to do that. Noise on the inputs or on the weights, weight decay, early stopping, [dropout](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0580). The latter seems to be the best nowadays. But you will still have to cross validate.

2) Depends on the data. Generally, if you know there are seasonal trends it would be stupid not to tell the network about it in some way. E.g. by filtering your data.